# Determine if the paragraph is a standard text or a heading

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, word-addins

Is there a way to determine if the paragraph is a standard text or a heading?

Without using any third party components like `Spire.Doc`

Please note the following Code: This works only if the Word Style "Heading 1" is not renamed.

```
object thisTempStyle = p.get_Style();
Style thisparagraphStyle = thisTempStyle as Style;
string actualStyle = thisparagraphStyle.NameLocal;

if (actualStyle == "Heading 1")
...
```

So, i'd like to get the Headings without knowing their names.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check the outline level of the paragraph
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839401.aspx).

```
switch(thisparagraphStyle.ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel)
{
  case WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel1:
    // Heading 1
    break; 
  case WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevelBodyText:
    // Body Paragraph
    break;
}
```

Comment: Woow, great! That's exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you!